# How do I build a vector of system::drawing::rectangle

Tags: .net, c++, vector, managed

How do I build a vector of system::drawing::rectangle in c++?
I tried vecor of std but got an error message that mixed types are not supported.  What can I do?

Comment: Why are you trying to combine `std::vector` with .NET Framework objects? Stick with the .NET collections, like `List<T>` or `Collection<T>`.

Comment: Which one is most similar to std::vector?

Comment: Both. Either one. It doesn't matter. `std::vector` is a dynamic array. So are `List<T>` and `Collection<T>`. That's not really the question, though. The question is why are you trying to use `std::vector` in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Array or List or other .Net collection.

Example:

```
List<System::Drawing::Rectangle>^ rectangles = gcnew List<System::Drawing::Rectangle>();
```

Note - If you are using VS2010 you can simplify this to:

```
auto rectangles = gcnew List<System::Drawing::Rectangle>();
```

Comment: I'm not using vs2010 :-(.  How do I deep copy a list object?

Comment: Have you searched Stack Overflow for an existing answer to that question?

Comment: I just looked.  The answer there is in c#.  I am in c++.  Is it the same?